# Expectation and Variance of a Binomial sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability

> Before a bank opens, customers begin to arrive from 8 a.m. onwards. They arrive independently such that the number that arrive in any 1 minute interval is a Poisson random variable with mean $3$. A bank employee randomly checks the line-up $M$ minutes after 8 a.m, where $M$ is a binomial r.v. with $p =0.8$ and $n = 20$. 
>  
>  a) Find the expected number of customers in the queue when it is checked.
>   b) What is the standard deviation of the number of customers in the queue when it is checked?

My thoughts: 
Since the $E[ X]$ of a Poission random variable is just $\lambda$, I feel like the answer for a) is just $3$. However, this seems way to easy.

Also, for b), the SD for a Poission is $\sqrt{\lambda}$, so is it just $\sqrt{3}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of customers $X$ can be expressed as a sum of the customers that arrive before the bank employee checks the line after $M$ minutes. In other words, we can write $X$ as
\begin{align*}
X = \sum_{i=1}^M Y_i
\end{align*}
where $Y_i$ is distributed Pois$(\lambda = 3)$. We wish to compute the expected value of $X$. Using the tower property of conditional expectations, we find
\begin{align*}
E(X) &= E(E(X \mid M)) \\
&= E(ME(Y_i)) \\
&= E(M \cdot 3) \\
&= 3 E(M) \\
&= 3 np = 3 \cdot 20 \cdot 0.8 = 48
\end{align*}
So the expected number of customers in line by the time the banker checks is 48.

The standard deviation $\sigma$ is the square root of the variance of $X$. Recall the law of total variance,
\begin{align*}
Var(X) &= E(Var(X \mid M)) + Var(E(X \mid M)) \\
&= E\Big(\sum_{i=1}^M Var(Y_i)\Big) + Var(3M) \\
&= E(M Var(Y_1)) + 9 Var(M) \\
&= E(M \cdot 3) + 9 n p (1-p) \\
&= 3np + 9 np(1-p) \\
&= 3 \cdot 20 \cdot 0.8 + 9 \cdot 20 \cdot 0.8 \cdot 0.2 \\
&= 48 + 28.8 = 76.8
\end{align*}
Taking the square root, we recover the standard deviation of $X$ to be $\sigma = \sqrt{76.8} \approx 8.76$

Comment: how do we know that $Y_i$ is distributed Pois$(\lambda = 3)$, and would it matter if it was another distribution that was not Poisson?

Comment: $Y_i$ is the number of people who arrive during the $i^{th}$ minute. It is stated in the problem that this r.v. is distributed Poisson with mean 3. The distribution matters since we plug in $E(Y_i) = 3$. If $Y_i$ were distributed according to some other distribution with mean $\mu$, we would plug in $\mu$ for $E(Y_i)$ instead of 3.

Answer (score 2):

"Random sum of Random Variables":  $X = \sum_{i=1}^M Y_i,$ where 
$Y_i \sim Pois(\lambda = 3),\,$ $M \sim Binom(n=20,p=.8),$ with all
random variables independent.

Let's simulate a million realizations of $X$ using R statistical software.
Results agree to three significant digits with the Answer of @DanielXiang (+1).
Notice in particular that the there are *two* components to $Var(X),$ so it
is larger than just $np\lambda.$

```
 B = 10^6;  lam = 3;  n = 20;  p = .8;  x = numeric(B)
 for (i in 1:B) {
   M = rbinom(1, n, p);  y = rpois(M, lam)  # if M=0, then y=0
   x[i] = sum(y)  }
 mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 48.01645  # aprx E(X) = 48.0
 ## 8.771066  # aprx SD(X) = 8.77
```

Below is a histogram of the simulated distribution, compared with the PDF
of $Norm(48, 8.77).$ The distribution of $X$ is slightly right-skewed, but nearly normal.

[image]